# Category with lot of pages (huge offsets) (how does stackoverflow work?)

Tags: mysql, database

I think that my question can be solved by just knowing how, for example, stackoverflow works.

For example, this page, loads in a few ms (< 300ms):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=61440&sort=newest

The only query i can think about for that page is something like `SELECT * FROM stuff ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT {pageNumber}*{stuffPerPage}, {pageNumber}*{stuffPerPage}+{stuffPerPage}`

A query like that might take several seconds to run, but the stack overflow page loads almost in no time. It can't be a cached query, since that question are posted over time and rebuild the cache every time a question is posted is simply madness.

So, how do this works in your opinion?

(to make the question easier, let's forget about the ORDER BY)
Example (the table is fully cached in ram and stored in an ssd drive)

```
mysql> select * from thread limit 1000000, 1;
1 row in set (1.61 sec)

mysql> select * from thread limit 10000000, 1;
1 row in set (16.75 sec)

mysql> describe select * from thread limit 1000000, 1;
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | thread | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 64801163 |       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------+

mysql> select * from thread ORDER BY thread_date DESC limit 1000000, 1;
1 row in set (1 min 37.56 sec)


mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM thread;
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| thread |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | newsgroup_id | A         |      102924 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| thread |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | thread_id    | A         |    47036298 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| thread |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | postcount    | A         |    47036298 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| thread |          0 | PRIMARY  |            4 | thread_date  | A         |    47036298 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| thread |          1 | date     |            1 | thread_date  | A         |    47036298 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have an index on date? That query shouldn't take long to run at all...

Comment: True but i suppose to be at least 1M questions :)

Comment: Just to make sure I'm on the right page, can you do `describe select * from thread limit 1000000, 1;`

Comment: What dates have you inserted? Are they all the same for every record?

Answer (score 2):

Create a BTREE index on date column <strike>and the query will run in a breeze</strike>.

```
CREATE INDEX date ON stuff(date) USING BTREE
```

---

UPDATE: Here is a test I just did:

```
CREATE TABLE test( d DATE, i INT, INDEX(d) );
```

Filled the table with 2,000,000 rows with different unique `i`s and `d`s

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 1000000, 1;
+------------+---------+
| d          | i       |
+------------+---------+
| 1897-07-22 | 1000000 |
+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.66 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY d LIMIT 1000000, 1;
+------------+--------+
| d          | i      |
+------------+--------+
| 1897-07-22 | 999980 |
+------------+--------+
1 row in set (1.68 sec)
```

And here is an interesiting observation:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY d LIMIT 1000, 1;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | index | NULL          | d    | 4       | NULL | 1001 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY d LIMIT 10000, 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2000343 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
```

MySql does use the index for OFFSET 1000 but not for 10000.

Even more interesting, if I do `FORCE INDEX` query takes more time:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test FORCE INDEX(d) ORDER BY d LIMIT 1000000, 1;
+------------+--------+
| d          | i      |
+------------+--------+
| 1897-07-22 | 999980 |
+------------+--------+
1 row in set (2.21 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, but there already is an index on that. Updated the question.

Comment: What is the point of OFFSET without ORDER BY? The position of rows will be undetermined without an ORDER BY. Also please post your queries with `ORDER BY date` and their corresponding times too.

Comment: @cedival Check out the test I just did.

Comment: @nobody In this situation MySQL optimizer incorrectly drops the index, but it's not a big problem, we can always force it: `force index (index_name)`. In any case, index scan will not be extremely fast if the offset is equal to 1.000.000 or more.

Comment: Can you provide tests with `order by d DESC`?

Comment: @Fatal Tried `ORDER BY d DESC` takes almost exact same time as 'ASC'.

Comment: @nobody I did tests on a table with more than 10 million rows and I haven't noticed such anomalies. For me the sorting takes forever without index. It's absolutely impossible that query with 1 million records sorts the table in 1.68 seconds.

Comment: @nobody Perhaps you can try to run with `IGNORE INDEX (d)`?

Comment: @nobody expected this but was not sure

Comment: @Karolis of course it can with a proper, efficient index. That's why I asked Question Opener what dates he inserted.

Comment: @nobody ok, i did some investigation. It seems that for _relatively_ smaller tables it's true. Perhaps it's because all the sorting job can be done in RAM. But for big tables MySQL optimizer uses wrong  execution plan. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think StackOverflow doesn't need to reach the rows at offset 10000000. The query below should be fast enough if you have an index on `date` and the numbers in `LIMIT` clause are from real world examples, not millions :)

```
SELECT * 
FROM stuff 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT {pageNumber}*{stuffPerPage}, {stuffPerPage}
```

**UPDATE:**

If records in a table are relatively rarely deleted (like in StackOverflow) then you can use the following solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stuff 
WHERE id between 
    {stuffCount}-{pageNumber}*{stuffPerPage}+1 AND 
    {stuffCount}-{pageNumber-1}*{stuffPerPage}
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Where `{stuffCount}` is:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM stuff
```

If you have some deleted records in a database then some pages will have less than {stuffPerPage} records, but it should not be the problem. StackOverflow uses some inaccurate algorithm too. For instance try to go to the first page and to the last page and you'll see that both pages return 30 records per page. But mathematically it's nonsense.

Solutions designed to work with large databases often uses some hacks which usually are unnoticeable for regular users.

---

*Nowadays paging with millions of records is not modish, because it's impractical. Currently it's popular to use infinite scrolling (automatic or manual with button click). It has more sense and pages load faster because they don't need to be reloaded. If you think that old records can be useful for your users too, then it's a good idea to create a page with random records (with infinite scrolling too). This was my opinion :)*

Comment: An offset of A million, is a real word example for my database :)
I suppose this to be also true on stack overflow :)

Comment: You could also do `SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE id between {stuffCount}-{pageNumber}*{stuffPerPage}+1 AND {stuffCount}-{pageNumber-1}*{stuffPerPage}+{extraRows} ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT {stuffPerPage}`, `extraRows` being some number of extra rows to fetch to make-up for any gaps in the table

Comment: @shesek Actually I had this in my mind when I was writing the answer but decided to leave this up to the question's author because it's just an example. But it's a good point!

Comment: IIRC, `SELECT MAX(id) FROM stuff` should be faster than `SELECT id FROM stuff ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @shesek No, this will not be faster. The speed will be the same. In any case you are right, my query is not very usual in programming practice. Actually I don't know why I created so funny solution for simple max(id) :)

Comment: @Karolis you're right - I benchmarked it, and, at least under Postgres, it takes about the same time. I dunno why I thought `MAX(id)` should be faster.

Comment: @shesek For more complicated queries when it's difficult to use an index for sorting then max(id) is a faster solution.

Comment: @cedivad So, what do you think about this solution to use id for paging? :)